# How could I prove that A\B = B\A iff A=B ??

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A\B = B\A if, and only if, A=B
I'm getting lost in this question. I know that I have to use the double inclusion to prove an equality, like B\A ⊂ A\B and then A\B ⊂ B\A. Therefore, I would have to prove that if A\B = B\A then A=B.

Does anybody could help me pls?

Comment: Note that $A\setminus B\cap B\setminus A=\varnothing$...

Comment: @JoseSquare Not true. If $A=B$, the former condition holds, even if they are non-empty.

Comment: @DonThousand yep, I got confused, what is $\emptyset$ is $A\backslash B = B \backslash A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction $A=B \Rightarrow A\setminus B=B\setminus A$ is immediate.

So suppose that $A\setminus B=B\setminus A$. you need to show that $x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B$ so that $A\subseteq B$. By symmetry you'll have also $B\subseteq A$ and $A=B$.

The details :

> Let $x\in A$. Suppose that $x \notin B$, then $x \in A\setminus B$. By our assumptions that $A\setminus B=B\setminus A$, we have $x \in B\setminus A$, contradicting the fact that $x \notin B$
>  so that  $x \in B$ and $A\subseteq B$. 
>  using symmtric arguments, ordirectly arguing about symmetry of the statement, we alse have $B \subseteq A$ and finally $A=B$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A \neq B$. Then $\exists x \in A : x \notin B$ or $\exists x \in B : x \notin A$. If $ x \in A$ and $x \notin B$, then clearly, $x \in A - B$ and $x \notin B-A$. Likewise, $x \in B$ and $x \notin A$ implies that $x \in B-A$ and $x \notin A-B$. It follows by necessity that $A=B$.

Comment: The converse is easily proved.